# short way to filter Objects on a ID

Tags: java

I want to filter Companys based on there Id's. This is how my code looks like:

```
List<Company> vendors = new ArrayList<Company>();
    descriptions.stream().forEach(desc -> {
        long vendorID = desc.getCompany().getId().getLongValue();
        if (vendors.stream().filter(vendor -> vendor.getId().getLongValue() == vendorID).count() == 0) {
            vendors.add(desc.getCompany());
        }
    });
return vendors;
```

My code works but I want to know if there is a shorter way.

Comment: Should be posted there [codereview.se]

Comment: How is `Company` declared? Edit your question and add an [MCWE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The code does not "filter companies based on their IDs". The code takes a list of Descriptions, extracts a Company from each of them and returns a list of unique Companies found in the process. If you cannot communicate what the code does to other human beings, you will not easily describe it to a machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are creating a List of `Company` instances taken from the `descriptions` `Collection` having unique identifiers.

Now, assuming that a `Company`'s identifier is unique, and that two `Company` instances having the same identifier are `equals` to each other (i.e. your  `Company` class overrides `equals` in a way that tests equality by comparing the identifiers), you can simply collect the distinct `Company` instances :

```
List<Company> vendors =
    descriptions.stream()
                .map(Description::getCompany)
                .distinct()
                .collect (Collectors.toList());
```